# Exception info from a ThreadAbortedException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I get an exception at response.redirect() and Visual Studio does not help me with appropriate info. I only get this for `ex:expression cannot be evaluated`, `message:subprocess annulled` and `_HResult:-2146233040`. I don't get a helplink or anything else.

```
  Try

        Dim unidadD As String = Request.QueryString("unity")
        Dim categD As String = Request.QueryString("category")
        Dim resulD As String = Request.QueryString("result")
        Dim anioD As String = Request.QueryString("year")
        Dim cicloD As String = Request.QueryString("cicle")

        Response.Redirect("~/Evaluacion/Detalle_Resultados.aspx?op=1" & "&unity=" & unidadD & "&category=" & categD & "&result=" & resulD & "&cicle=" & cicloD & "&year=" & anioD)


       Catch exa As System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
           Dim link As String = exa.HelpLink
        End Try
```

Comment: call `exa.ToString()` to get everything you need to figure out your problem.

Comment: Looks like you just typed the wrong exception name in the debugger somewhere (ex instead of exa)

Comment: Joel you can use any varname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) is expected to throw a `ThreadAbortedException`. Simply move the Response.Redirect out of the try/catch block.

Another option is to use:

```
Response.Redirect(url, False)
```

This will redirect without ending the current request. You can later call [`Application.CompleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx).

Another alternative would be

```
Try
    Response.Redirect(url)
Catch tax as ThreadAbortedException
    ' Do nothing, as this is an expected exception
    ' No need to rethrow, as this exception is automatically re-thrown
End Try
```

Comment: Alright so no need to put a response.redirect sentence never in a try/catch block?, i alwasy put everythin inside those

Comment: Or else use `Response.Redirect(url, False)`, or you could use `Catch tax As ThreadAbortException`, `'Do nothing`, `End Try`

Answer (score 1):

This is [expected](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us) behaviour, as a workaround just pass `false` in `Response.Redirect` e.g.

```
Response.Redirect("...", false);
```

Or as already suggested, get rid of the `Try...Catch` - not quite sure what you expect to do with a `ThreadAbortException` anyway...

Comment: i add that exception trying to get more info after the general exception does not provide enough information. Does a list exist to why some exceptions occurs?